# Tkinter - "Label" object is not callable ; NOT a case of naming an object after LABEL class

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend

I'm working on a tkinter GUI API-based application.

I'm attempting to modularize my code in which each function has a specific task to do and some functions just call other functions.

In my case, I bind the `search` button to the function, `search`, whose job is to call other API-based functions, such as `full_name`.

When I did this, an error is thrown, saying that `in search full_name() TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable`

what's interesting is that

1. I see no mention of creating instances of Label classes in `full_name()`
2. when I bind the `search` button to function, `full_name()`, it works just fine. However, I want to bind it to a function that will call all API-based functions, and so far, it's not working

Here's the code below:

```
#MER for frames placement through .Grid() 

#import necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.title("F1 Desktop Application")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.configure(bg="white")


#generate 2022 drivers-list [can scale to drivers-list by changing the]
drivers_list_request = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/drivers.json")
#initialize empty-list
drivers_list = []
drivers_list_object = json.loads(drivers_list_request.content)

for elements in drivers_list_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"]:
    drivers_list.append(elements["givenName"] + " " + elements["familyName"])

#NEED TO UNDERSTAND PRECEDENCE BETWEEN WIDTH, HEIGHT SETTING, VS SPANS. STICKY MAKES PERFECT SENSE
top_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 300, height = 125)
top_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
top_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 75)
top_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 300)

# Update the Entry widget with the selected item in list
def check(e):
    
    v= entry_box.get()

    if v=='':
        hide_button(menu)
    
    else:
        data=[]
        for item in drivers_list:
            if v.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)
        
        update(data)
        show_button(menu)

def update(data):
   # Clear the Combobox
   menu.delete(0, END)
   # Add values to the combobox
   for value in data:
        menu.insert(END,value)
        
def fillout(event):
    
    try:
        
        entry_box.delete(0,END)
        
        entry_box.insert(0,menu.get(menu.curselection()))
        
        hide_button(menu)
        
    #handle a complete deletion of entry-box via cursor double tap
    except:
        
        pass
        
def hide_button(widget):
    widget.grid_remove()
    
def show_button(widget):
    widget.grid()
    
def full_name():
    
    user_input = entry_box.get()
    
    
    lower_user_input = user_input.lower().split(" ")[1]
    
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}.json".format(lower_user_input))
    
    print(response.status_code)

    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
    
    name = response_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"][0]["givenName"] + " " + response_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"][0]["familyName"]
    
    print(name)



def search():
    
    full_name()
    
    

    
    
 
    
    
    #once works, then make API request




header_label = Label(top_frame, text = "F1 2022 Drivers App", font = ("Arial bold",14), bg = "white")
header_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 30)

search_button = Button(top_frame, text = "search" , command = search)
search_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

entry_box= Entry(top_frame)
entry_box.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entry_box.bind('<KeyRelease>',check)

menu= Listbox(top_frame, height = 4)
menu.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
menu.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",fillout)






left_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 250, height = 225, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 2)
left_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = NW, padx = 10, pady = 15)
#left_frame.grid_propagate(False)
left_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 100)
left_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 200)

#left_frame_content = LabelFrame(, width = 125, height = 70)
#left_frame_content.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)


basic_info = Label(left_frame, text = "Basic Info ", font = ("Arial bold",14))
basic_info.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

full_name = Label(left_frame, text = "Full Name :")
full_name.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

driver_code = Label(left_frame, text = "Driver Code : ")
driver_code.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

nationality = Label(left_frame, text = "Nationality : ")
nationality.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)





bottom_left_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 250, height = 225)
bottom_left_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = N, padx = 10)
bottom_left_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 50)
bottom_left_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 200)





F1_career = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "F1 Career ", font = ("Arial bold",14))
F1_career.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

wins = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Wins :")
wins.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

wins.configure(text = "Wins :" + " 7")

poles = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Poles :")
poles.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

test = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "test")
test.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

podiums = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Podiums :")
podiums.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

podiums.configure(text = "Podiums :" + "Lewis Hamilton")

drivers_championships = Label(bottom_left_frame, text = "Championships :")
drivers_championships.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)





bottom_right_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 250, height = 225)
bottom_right_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

bottom_right_frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 50)
bottom_right_frame.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 150)

hide_button(menu)





root.mainloop()
```

Feel free to ask for more clarity. I would be grateful if anyone has a reason/solution

Comment: You have used the same name for an instance of `Label`: `full_name = Label(left_frame, text = "Full Name :")`. It overrides the function `full_name()`.

Comment: "I see no mention of creating instances of Label classes in full_name()" You did not read the error message correctly. The error is telling you that **the code** `full_name()` causes the problem, and that code is `in` the `search` function. "NOT a case of naming an object after LABEL class" The problem is not when you use the name of the class for a different object. The problem is when you have an object *which is an instance of the class*, and use the name *of a function* for that instance. Here, `full_name` is the name of a Label: `full_name = Label(left_frame, text = "Full Name :")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the same name for a label:

```py
full_name = Label(left_frame, text = "Full Name :")
```

So it will override the `full_name()`.

Use another name for the label, for example `full_name_label`:

```py
full_name_label = Label(left_frame, text = "Full Name :")
full_name_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Comment: appreciate all of your guys' help! made sense; need to get better at reading error messages